# How to import product images programmatically with the use of custom script in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, import, media-images, dynamic

I have all product images in one folder. Images are in path like - pub/media/Fotos/MA/{{ sku }}/

So need to import images as per SKU folder. I want dynamic script for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have created one custom script and it is working properly in my case.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
 
$params = $_SERVER;
 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

$productCollectionFactory = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$mediaAttribute = array('thumbnail','small_image','image');

$fp = fopen('skuimage.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
$k = 1;

foreach($collection as $collec)
{
    $productRepository = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $productObj = $productRepository->get($collec->getSku());

    echo "Count Product->".$k."<-ID->".$collec->getEntityId();

    $productimages = $productObj->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if(count($productimages) > 0) {
        $msg = 'Product has already images. Product ID: ' . $productObj->getId();
        echo $msg . '<br />';
    } else {
        $dirname = BP."/pub/media/Fotos/MA/".$collec->getSku().'/';
        if(is_dir($dirname)) {
            $images = glob($dirname.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}',GLOB_BRACE);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                if(file_exists($image)) {
                    echo "file exist";
                    if($i == 0) {
                        $productObj->setStoreId(0);
                        $productObj->addImageToMediaGallery($image, $mediaAttribute, false, false);
                    } else {
                        $productObj->addImageToMediaGallery($image, null, false, false);
                    }
                    try {
                        $productObj->save();
                    } catch(\Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
            $msg = 'Product image saved. Product ID: ' . $productObj->getId();
        } else {
            fputcsv($fp, array($collec->getSku()), ",");
        }
    }
    $k++;
}
fclose($fp);
```